LINE Messaging API Webhook stuck in "standby" mode despite being set to "active"
I'm currently facing an issue with my LINE Messaging API webhook being stuck in "standby" mode even though it's set to "active" in the LINE Console and through the Messaging API.
Here are the steps I've followed:

Set the Messaging API webhook via the developer console, and verification was successful.
Enabled the "Use webhook" option in the LINE Developer Console.
pic for both No.1 and 2
Enabled "Webhook" under the response settings in the LINE Official Account (OA).
pic for No.3
Sent a GET request using Postman to https://api.line.me/v2/bot/channel/webhook/endpoint and received a response confirming the webhook is active.
pic for No.4

I have checked for possible conflicts or other active webhooks but couldn't find any.
However, when sending messages to the bot, the events received by my webhook still show "mode": "standby", and I can't figure out why.
Requestbody with standby mode
Any advice on how to ensure my webhook switches to "active" would be greatly appreciated.
